# Formatting output to file with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, formatting, domdocument

So I wrote this script that looks for certain nodes in an XML file, deletes it, and puts a new node in it's place... however, the new node is showing up like so:

```
<PrintQuestion id="17767" type="pickOne">

<Standards><Standard value="CA.MATH-6-6-20" state="CA" grade="3" subject="MATH"/></Standards><References>
        <PassageRef id="1892"/>
    </References>
```

I've attempted to use the $xml->formatOutput = true;  but that has done nothing.  I'm loading the dom object from an XML file and saving it back to the same file upon completion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP XML how to output nice format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615422/php-xml-how-to-output-nice-format)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to use

```
$xml->formatOutput = TRUE;
```

you also have to set

```
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
```

You wrote `preserveWhitespace` (mind the 2nd *s*). Properties are case-sensitive in PHP.

[See difference on codepad](http://codepad.org/fIsZ1qz7)

Comment: WOW... I can't believe I didn't notice that.  Thanks!