# PHP XML how to output nice format

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Here are the codes:

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
// create root node
$root = $doc->createElement('root');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$signed_values = array('a' => 'eee', 'b' => 'sd', 'c' => 'df');
// process one row at a time
foreach ($signed_values as $key => $val) {
    // add node for each row
    $occ = $doc->createElement('error');
    $occ = $root->appendChild($occ);
    // add a child node for each field
    foreach ($signed_values as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
        $child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
        $child = $occ->appendChild($child);
        $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
        $value = $child->appendChild($value);
    }
}
// get completed xml document
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML() ;
echo $xml_string;
```

If I print it in the browser I don't get nice XML structure like

```
<xml> \n tab <child> etc.
```

I just get

```
<xml><child>ee</child></xml>
```

And I want to be utf-8
How is this all possible to do?

Comment: About your utf-8 issue, just add it to the object as a second parameter like `$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
...
// get completed xml document
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

You can make set these parameter right after you've created the `DOMDocument` as well:

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
```

That's probably more concise. Output in both cases is ([Demo](http://codepad.org/e0IHyrKz)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <error>
    <a>eee</a>
    <b>sd</b>
    <c>df</c>
  </error>
  <error>
    <a>eee</a>
    <b>sd</b>
    <c>df</c>
  </error>
  <error>
    <a>eee</a>
    <b>sd</b>
    <c>df</c>
  </error>
</root>
```

I'm not aware how to change the indentation character(s) with `DOMDocument`. You could post-process the XML with a line-by-line regular-expression based replacing (e.g. with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)):

```
$xml_string = preg_replace('/(?:^|\G)  /um', "\t", $xml_string);
```

Alternatively, there is the [tidy extension with `tidy_repair_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php) which can pretty print XML data as well. It's possible to specify indentation levels with it, however tidy will never output tabs.

```
tidy_repair_string($xml_string, ['input-xml'=> 1, 'indent' => 1, 'wrap' => 0]);
```

Comment: Related: [*Debug a DOMDocument Object in PHP*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/684227/367456) for a more controlled form of XML printing.

Comment: Related: [*Converting indentation with preg_replace (no callback)*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8616594/367456)

Comment: I've discovered that *"You can make set these parameter right after you've created the DOMDocument as well"* is not a great idea if you use `saveXML` while processing/comparing it with another document because it can lead to unexpected results. Best to format output right before you need to output.

Answer (score 41):

With a SimpleXml object, you can simply

```
$domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$domxml->formatOutput = true;
/* @var $xml SimpleXMLElement */
$domxml->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$domxml->save($newfile);
```

`$xml` is your simplexml object

So then you simpleXml can be saved as a new file specified by `$newfile`

Comment: @quickshiftin - Input data is an instance of `SimpleXMLElement`. I'll edit the answer to make it more obvious. Whatever, I agree that what you feed `DOMDocument` with is actually irrelevant.

Comment: additionally, you can use ` $domxml->encoding = "UTF-8"` after `loadXML` before `save`.

Answer (score 24):

```
<?php

$xml = $argv[1];

$dom = new DOMDocument();

// Initial block (must before load xml string)
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
// End initial block

$dom->loadXML($xml);
$out = $dom->saveXML();

print_R($out);
```

Comment: could you also add an explanation?

Answer (score 12):

Tried all the answers but none worked. Maybe it's because I'm appending and removing childs before saving the XML.
After a lot of googling found [this comment](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php#96055) in the php documentation. I only had to reload the resulting XML to make it work.

```
$outXML = $xml->saveXML(); 
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$xml->formatOutput = true; 
$xml->loadXML($outXML); 
$outXML = $xml->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// ##### IN SUMMARY #####

$xmlFilepath = 'test.xml';
echoFormattedXML($xmlFilepath);

/*
 * echo xml in source format
 */
function echoFormattedXML($xmlFilepath) {
    header('Content-Type: text/xml'); // to show source, not execute the xml
    echo formatXML($xmlFilepath); // format the xml to make it readable
} // echoFormattedXML

/*
 * format xml so it can be easily read but will use more disk space
 */
function formatXML($xmlFilepath) {
    $loadxml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFilepath);

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($loadxml->asXML());
    $formatxml = new SimpleXMLElement($dom->saveXML());
    //$formatxml->saveXML("testF.xml"); // save as file

    return $formatxml->saveXML();
} // formatXML
```

Comment: upvoted, because this answer contains a complete example!

Comment: Great answer, this was the only option that fully worked in my circumstance (working with RSS XML).

Answer (score 4):

Two different issues here:

- Set the [formatOutput](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput) and [preserveWhiteSpace](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace) attributes to `TRUE` to generate formatted XML:

  ```
  $doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
  ```
- Many web browsers (namely Internet Explorer and Firefox) format XML when they display it. Use either the View Source feature or a regular text editor to inspect the output.

---

See also [xmlEncoding](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.xmlencoding) and [encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.encoding).

Comment: `preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE` can get in your way when you do pretty printing with `DOMDocument` - just FYI, not with the example given in question, but if you load from existing files that have actually whitespace textnodes.

Comment: @hakre Why `preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE` works fine with XML, but doesn't work with HTML?

Comment: To let the browser format it, a proper MIME type has to be set. For example whit:
header('Content-type: text/xml');

Comment: I actually neeeded to see the whitespaces, so this was the correct answer for me

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight variation of the above theme but I'm putting here in case others hit this and cannot make sense of it ...as I did.

When using saveXML(), preserveWhiteSpace in the target DOMdocument does not apply to imported nodes (as at PHP 5.6).

Consider the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();                               //create a document
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;                       //disable whitespace preservation
$dom->formatOutput = true;                              //pretty print output
$documentElement = $dom->createElement("Entry");        //create a node
$dom->appendChild ($documentElement);                   //append it 
$message = new DOMDocument();                           //create another document
$message->loadXML($messageXMLtext);                     //populate the new document from XML text
$node=$dom->importNode($message->documentElement,true); //import the new document content to a new node in the original document
$documentElement->appendChild($node);                   //append the new node to the document Element
$dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);                   //print the original document
```

In this context,  the `$dom->saveXML();` statement will NOT pretty print the content imported from $message, but content originally in $dom will be pretty printed.

In order to achieve pretty printing for the entire $dom document, the line:

```
$message->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
```

must be included after the `$message = new DOMDocument();` line - ie. the document/s from which the nodes are imported must also have preserveWhiteSpace = false.

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer by @heavenevil
This function pretty prints using the browser

```php
function prettyPrintXmlToBrowser(SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    $domXml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $domXml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $domXml->formatOutput = true;
    $domXml->loadXML($xml->asXML());
    $xmlString = $domXml->saveXML();
    echo nl2br(str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', htmlspecialchars($xmlString)));
}
```