# PHP DOM generated XML break line

Tags: php, xml, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP XML how to output nice format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615422/php-xml-how-to-output-nice-format)

I have the following PHP DOM code that creates a XML document in a dynamic way:

```
<?php

// create doctype
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
// display document in browser as plain text
// for readability purposes
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
// create root element
$root = $dom->createElement("toppings");
$dom->appendChild($root);
// create child element
$item = $dom->createElement("item");
$root->appendChild($item);
// create text node
$text = $dom->createTextNode("pepperoni");
$item->appendChild($text);
}
// save and display tree
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

The PHP code generates the next XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<toppings><item>pepperoni</item></toppings>
<toppings><item>pepperoni</item></toppings>
<toppings><item>pepperoni</item></toppings>
<toppings><item>pepperoni</item></toppings>
<toppings><item>pepperoni</item></toppings>
```

I would like to know what to change in order for the XML look like this other way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<toppings>
  <item>pepperoni</item>
</toppings>
<toppings>
  <item>pepperoni</item>
</toppings>
<toppings>
  <item>pepperoni</item>
</toppings>
<toppings>
  <item>pepperoni</item>
</toppings>
<toppings>
  <item>pepperoni</item>
</toppings>
```

Comment: Minor sidenote; especially with PHP scripts that output something, be careful of the closing '?>'. It can cause an empty line at the end of your output that can bork up other scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `$dom->formatOutput = true`.

Comment: Add this along with above is working fine for me:-> 
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;