# Updating a xml file in a formatted text with php simplexml tool

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP XML how to output nice format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615422/php-xml-how-to-output-nice-format)

i'm using this

```
<?php

$file = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/payback_service/payback_records.xml';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $sxe = simplexml_load_file($file);  
    $movie = $sxe->addChild('record');
    $movie->addChild('lat', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
    $movie->addChild('lng', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');
    $movie->addChild('address', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
    $movie->addChild('picture_link', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
    $movie->addChild('message', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
    $sxe->asXML($file);


} else {
    exit('Failed to open '.$file);
}
```

i want the text of the xml being updated in a formatted form.

right now i am getting this:

```
<record><lat>PHP2: More Parser Stories</lat><lng>This is all about the people who make it work.</lng><address>PHP2: More Parser Stories</address><picture_link>PHP2: More Parser Stories</picture_link><message>PHP2: More Parser Stories</message></record><record><lat>PHP2: More Parser Stories</lat><lng>This is all about the people who make it work.</lng><address>PHP2: More Parser Stories</address><picture_link>PHP2: More Parser Stories</picture_link><message>PHP2: More Parser Stories</message></record></root>
```

i need the file to be like this:

```
<record>
    <lat>1.5</lat>
    <lng>-8.5</lng>
    <address>this is the address</address>
    <picture_link>this is picture link</picture_link>
    <message>this is the message</message>
</record>
<record>
    <lat>1.5</lat>
    <lng>0.248</lng>
    <address>PHP2: More Parser Stories</address>
    <picture_link>PHP2: More Parser Stories</picture_link>
    <message>PHP2: More Parser Stories</message>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SimpleXML supports formatting. However the [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) does:

```
<?php

$file = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/payback_service/payback_records.xml';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $sxe = simplexml_load_file($file);  
    $movie = $sxe->addChild('record');
    $movie->addChild('lat', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
    $movie->addChild('lng', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');
    $movie->addChild('address', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
    $movie->addChild('picture_link', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
    $movie->addChild('message', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($sxe->asXML());
    echo $dom->saveXML();

} else {
    exit('Failed to open '.$file);
}
```