# How to test a class that generates XML internally

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

Currently I am working to test a class that generates XML based on a value object, sends the XML over HTTP and parses the XML response back into a second value object. I would like to test in this case the generated XML and the parsed value object based on a given XML.

The class looks like:

```
class MyClient
{
    public function send(RequestValues $request)
    {
        $document = $this->generateMessage($request);
        $response = $this->request($document);

        return $this->parseResponse($response);
    }

    protected function generateMessage(RequestValues $request)
    {
        $document = new DomDocument;
        // Do stuff with $request

        return $document;
    }

    public function request(DomDocument $document)
    {
        $client = $this->getHttpClient();
        $client->setRawBody($document->saveXml());
        // Configure client

        return $client->send();
    }

    public function parseResponse(Response $response)
    {
        $parameters = new ResponseValues;

        $document = new DomDocument;
        $document->loadXml($response->getBody());

        // Fill in $parameters
        return $parameters;
    }
}
```

I would like to test two things:

1. Given a certain `RequestValues` argument, the generated XML must look like `$string`
2. Given a certain XML response value (the HTTP client will be mocked), the `ResponseValues` must be equal to `$object`

I am now writing a test for #1, but I think I can only achieve this via a callback. The callback however, does not give me quite useful information when the test fails. Only this message:

> Failed asserting that DOMDocument Object () is accepted by specified callback.

The test looks like this:

```
public function testRequestContainsValidXml()
{
    $client  = $this->getMock('MyClient', array('request'));

    $message = '';
    $client->expects($this->once())
           ->method('request')
           ->with($this->callback(function($object) use ($message) {
                return
                    ($object instanceof DomDocument)
                 && ($object->saveXml() === $message);
            }));

    $request = new DirectoryRequest;
    $client->send($request);
}
```

The question is: **how can I improve the test** such that a normal string comparison is possible? I would love to get phpunit saying "string X is not equal to Y" which eases the debugging enormously.

PS. The complete code of this class is available on GitHub. Naturally, above example is a simplified version. Here's the actual class: https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmIdealPayment/blob/master/src/SlmIdealPayment/Client/StandardClient.php#L58

PPS. If the code must be changed in order to get it tested, that's not a problem. I'd only want to keep the public API the same (i.e. the call `ResponseValues send(RequestValues $request)`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it that the comparison `$object->saveXml() === $message` is failing?

Comment: @silkfire *if* the $message is correct, it wouldn't fail and just pass. However, there is no way to see what the difference is between the expected and actual string. You cannot debug this in any way with unit testing, something which is possible with e.g. `$this->assertEquals($string1, $string2)`. So rather that the unit tests help me understand the bugs in my code, it's a big black box and not really helpful if you accidentally have a bug.

Comment: So the question is (also put in bold) how can I **improve** the test. I can get it pass, but the problem is to get meaningful messages back from phpunit when it doesn't pass.

Comment: There are diff classes available for PHP that you can use to see what the difference is character by character; then you can call that diff function within the Unit test?

Comment: For example, **FineDiff** is really good; test their tool that utilizes the class live over here: http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php

Answer (score 0):

You class `MyClient` suggests that it is a facade. To test a facade in the context of UnitTests it is normally first of all necessary to test all units that are collaborators of that facade.

As you normally mock the collaborators - and not the unit under test - your test setup looks wrong as you're mocking the `MyClient` unit under test but not it's collaborators.

For example:

You want to test if the `MyClient::parseResponse()` method returns the expected `ResponseValues` object. Therefore you would mock the `Response` as it is a collaborator in this case.

You probably also want to mock the other collaborator (`ResponseValues`) however you can't as it is a hidden dependency that can not be injected (you could resolve this by injecting a factory to `MyClient` that can control the creation of such `ResponseValues`).

So much for testing `MyClient::parseResponse()`: You would inject the fixture XML via a `Response` mock and the run your assertions on the return value.

For the case to test if the request contains valid XML (`testRequestContainsValidXml()`), I don't think it should be done in that complicated form either. Sounds like you have a HTTP client here, you should only test that it works and don't care if it works with XML as well, because if it works, it works with XML as well. The reason why you test for valid XML is not because you want to test the client. So keep that test out of the client unit-tests.

The assertion for the string stuff btw. is:

```
$this->assertSame($expected, $actual);
```

Phpunit will show you a nice diff between the strings. Some other programmers / testers were also applying some XML normalization when they compared XML so that the diff is more readable. You might find a Q&A like [*PHP XML how to output nice format*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615485/367456) and related useful for that if your XML has no problem to deal with insignificant whitespace.

I hope I could pin-point the problem cases you face with this a little and broaden your view on the problem. I think you come most far with questioning your current mock usage critically, for the examples I give I have fully reduced mocking to providing collaborators, not to do assertions. Asswertions are only done on the unit under test, here the exemplary `MyClient`.