# Represent JSON data from one line string to structured source

Tags: php, json

I have **JSON** data in one line string. I want output it like structured source code, how can I do that in **PHP**?

Comment: [This can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) flag (PHP 5.4+):

```
$json_str = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Since you're having a JSON-string, you can first decode it into an object, and then re-encode it.

Example:

```
$str = '{"name":"John","age":"12","Location":"U.S.A"}';
echo json_encode(json_decode($str), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "12",
    "Location": "U.S.A"
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/99047)

Comment: Thanks, it works, maybe you know how to do the same with XML data string?

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko: Load the XML using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) class, set `$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false; $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;`, and then `$formatted_output = $dom->saveXML();` - but that's an entirely different question and should be posted as such - [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8615485/) should answer your question, though :)

Comment: Happy to have helped!