# PHP Curl Request with XML

Tags: php, xml, curl

I can not for the life of me figure out how to keep the formatting of XML in a string, even when echoing the string of `$data_string` I get the XML stripped out and only the values remain.

Then I need to be able to do a CURL request via PHP with that string, I'm not sure if I have the right setup for that though.

Code:

```
$data_string = '<test><name>John Doe</name><age>22</age><city>seattle</age></test>';

$curl = curl_init($baseUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xmlRequest=" . $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header",
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    "Accept: text/xml" )
);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Test:

```
echo $data_string;
```

Result:

```
John Doe22seattle
```

Comment: "I can not for the life of me" :))))))

Comment: try checking the source code of the page you're in, normally CTRL+U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the page you are echoing is ALSO using the MIME type `text/xml`.

Another way i can think of, is to escape the html characters using [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: htmlentities seemed to work, is there a way to pretty print it with that?

Comment: this seems promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615422/php-xml-how-to-output-nice-format#answer-8615485