# PHP XML modification indentation is lost

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am using a `DOMDocument` to add new nodes to an XML file using PHP. I am using the `createElement()` and `appendChild()` functions.

The problem is that the indentation of the tags in the XML is lost. How can I keep the indentation in the XML or re-indent after addition of a node?

My XML before modification is nicely indented:

```
<my_xml>
   <level>Some level</level>
</my_xml>
```

But after modification, the indentation is lost:

```
<my_xml>
   <level>Some level</level>
<level>New Level</level></my_xml>
```

Comment: try to follow answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615422/php-xml-how-to-output-nice-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this before you get the XML:

```
$dom->formatOutput = true;
```

Comment: Is the `$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` also needed, in the documentation it says that setting it to `false` means  'Do not remove redundant white space'? Surely, indentation must rely on redundant whitespaces?